# Can't get structuremap working with MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap3

I've created a default MVC5 web application in Visual Studio 2013, and added in the [StructureMap.MVC5](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.MVC5) package from NuGet.

I've created an interface `ITester` and an implementation `Tester`, and my controller action takes an `ITester` as a parameter.

But when I run the project I get the error `Cannot create an instance of an interface`.

According to [this](http://ardalis.com/resolving-dependencies-in-asp.net-mvc-5-with-structuremap) is should just work. I also get the same result if I explicitly tell structuremap to use `Tester` for `ITester` (rather than relying on the default conventions).

I've used [StructureMap.MVC4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC4/) with MVC4 web applications before with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box it's going to do constructor injection only.

This will work

```
public HomeController(ITester tester) 
{
  _tester = tester;
}
```

This will cause the error you are seeing

```
public ActionResult Index(ITester tester)
{
  return View();
}
```